# Raspi3 shows startx error

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

It is my first time using raspberry pi and I cant get through to the config interface. when I type startx, "-bash: startx: command not found" shows on the screen. I dont know what to do. help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

```html
sudo apt-get install X
```

sudo apt-get install X